# Mysql full text search with Laravel Translatable?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, translation

Up until now, I have always used a full text search like this:

```
public function posts($search)
{
    $searchString = $this->prepareString($search);
    $posts = Post::select('*')->selectRaw('MATCH(name) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS relevance', [$searchString])->whereRaw('MATCH(name) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)', [$searchString])->orderBy('relevance', 'desc')->get();

    return $posts;
}
```

And this works perfectly, however now I am using this package `Laravel Translatable`. And the `name` field is not part of the Post, but it is part of the PostTranslation. How can I use the above query, but for the translation? Here are my migrations:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
Schema::create('post_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('body');

            $table->char('locale', 2)->index();

            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unique(['id', 'locale']);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DB` Facade something like this

```
public function posts($search)
{
    $searchString = $this->prepareString($search);
    $posts = DB::table('post_translations')->select('*')->selectRaw('MATCH(name) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS relevance', [$searchString])->whereRaw('MATCH(name) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)', [$searchString])->orderBy('relevance', 'desc')->get();

    return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does not seem to support `FULLTEXT` indices to be specified in the migration using the table blueprint. You can however just add them manually using raw queries:

```
Schema::create('post_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('body');

    $table->char('locale', 2)->index();

    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->unique(['id', 'locale']);
});
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE post_translations ADD FULLTEXT idx(name)');
```

You can then just use the fulltext search as normal:

```
$posts = PostTranslation::select('*')
    ->selectRaw(
      'MATCH(name) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS relevance', 
      [$searchString]
    )->orderBy('relevance', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

very good

Schema::create('post_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');

```
$table->string('name');
$table->text('body');

$table->char('locale', 2)->index();

$table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->unique(['id', 'locale']);
```

});
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE post_translations ADD FULLTEXT idx(name)');

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).